# how to use HTML tags to format text in an EditText in android

Tags: android, html

my code looks like this

```
txtData=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textbox);
txtData.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><html></b>"));
```

as you can see i am trying to make HTML code appear in an EditText box. I am trying to use HTML tags using the Html.fromHtml() method to format the HTML code that appears in the box.
i need to find a way to escape the '<' and '>' tags around the word html from being processed by the fromHtml method. any suggestions on how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
txtData=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textbox);
txtData.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>&#60;html&#62;</b>"));
```

or

```
txtData=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textbox);
txtData.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>&lt;html&gt;</b>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
txtData.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>&#60;html&#62;<b>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
 &lt;
```

and

```
 &gt;
```

as in this example

```
txtData.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>&lt;html&gt;</b>"));
```

Comment: what is difference between your answer and my answer?